# Reading TIFF and DICOM images with lossless JPEG compression

Tags: c#, imagemagick, jpeg, tiff

I'm interested in any way to read TIFF image with **lossless JPEG** compressed data. I've tried ImageMagick, but it fails:

```
convert.exe: Unsupported JPEG process: SOF type 0xc3. `JPEGLib' @ error/tiff.c/TIFFErrors/562.
```

According to ImageMagick forum, there is no lossless JPEG support in official distribution of ImageMagick, but there is a patch that can help. The problem is this patch is a bit out of date.

I've also tried Leadtools and ImageGear libs; they worked well, but they are too much expensive for me.

So if there is any way to enable lossless JPEG processing in current versions of ImageMagick or there is any library, that can read such kind of images, please tell me.

Comment: ImageMagick is an open source project.  Clearly they are waiting for a contribution from a programmer that needs this patch to be updated.  A programmer with a itch that needs scratching or whose time doesn't cost money.  Clearly you are a perfectly good match. This is fundamental to the way foss works.  Good luck with it.

Comment: May be I will do that unless I will not find a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about TIFF, but GDCM does support lossless JPEG. Simply use it this way:

```
$ gdcmconv --raw jpeg.dcm uncompress.dcm
$ gdcm2pnm uncompress.dcm uncompress.ppm
```